# Should I put the in "Oak in the field" sentence?

Tags: articles

Let's say I have a photo of oak in field. I don't know anything about this field. Should I name photo "Oak in field", "Oak in a field" or "Oak in the field" and why ?

Comment: No, let’s please **not** say you “have photo of oak in field”. You cannot “have photo” in English, as that is ungrammatical. It’s shy an article or other determiner. Why are you using *oak* as a mass noun? Shouldn’t that be *oak trees* instead?  And what’s this “in field” bit?

Comment: @tchrist why having a photo is ungrammatical ? It's my stuff, I have it. How it should be ? There is one oak. Like here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Alentejo_oak_on_wheat_field.jpg

Comment: You said "I have photo". You can't say that. You have to say that you have ***a*** photo. And while *“Oak in field”* **might** under **some** circumstances be allowable in “headlinese” as **the** caption of **the** photo, you cannot in general say that in English because it doesn’t have **an** article. Clearly your own language lacks mandatory articles and perhaps even determiners, but English does not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can assume you have not referred to these things before (and you say this is the first time the field has been mentioned), all three nouns take an indefinite article.

> I have **a** photo of **an** oak in **a** field.

As for *naming* the photograph, that's entirely up to you. Some photograph (or painting or statue) names drop articles altogether, others use an indefinite article, and others use the definite article.